# JSON converter in Grails

Tags: json, grails, converters

Consider a simple class as :-

```
class Person{
     String name
     String email
     int age
     String mobileNum
}
```

I want to selectively send 'id' & 'email' attributes as JSON response.
When using:-

```
return theObject as JSON
```

the response has all attribute:value pair.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can register your own JSON marshaller (at `BootStrap.groovy`, for example), like:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Person) { Person it ->
  return [
    id    : it.id, 
    email : it.email 
  ]
}
```

Comment: Here is article about this aproach [Rendering JSON in Grails: Part 3 Customise your JSON with Object Marshallers](http://manbuildswebsite.com/2010/02/15/rendering-json-in-grails-part-3-customise-your-json-with-object-marshallers/)